# Huge data In DyGraph

Tags: asp.net, html, dygraphs

Using Dygraphs, I created a line chart for Temperature vs Time. In my database I have apprx 700k of records and it may keep on increasing on minute ticks. I can plot all the 700k of records in chart. The issue is fetching all those at once is killing time and it took apprx 15mins each time I refresh the page. This bombs out in realtime.

Is there a better way to handle millions of records with out any data size restriction? I did everything I can do. Is there any alternate library to handle such stuff?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. My solution is this great dygraphs extension:

http://kaliatech.github.io/dygraphs-dynamiczooming-example/

It works great with giant amounts of data (in my case about 10 to 15 million data rows). You only need to write some server-side code for fetching the aggregated data from the DB. In my case, I created a stored procedure in the DB itself that takes the start date, end date, some other ID's for datapoint identification and - most importantly - the period by which the values get grouped and aggregated. The data is requested and sent back via ajax almost instantly, so the frontend user gets a very smooth and responsive UI.

I aggregate the values in such a way that the number of datetime/value-pairs is equal to the width of the chart area in pixels, a finer resolution wouldn't be visible anyway. By doing so, you can minimize the amount of data that gets send "through the wire".

Answer (score 2):

Amongst all JavaScript charting libraries, dygraphs is generally considered to [handle large data sets well](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/html5-charting-tool-performance.html). If it's too slow for your needs, you should try downsampling your data or reducing the range of data that you show.

Comment: Just to add to @danvk's answer: while down-sampling is independent of dygraphs, dygraphs has been shown to be very useful in displaying and then interacting with down-sampled data. See discussion with links to examples here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dygraphs-users/kgdNdt1A0dk

Answer (score 0):

I have a charting app using Dygraphs routinely displaying well over 100,000 records and the only delay I can speak of is loading the data through the internet connection. Once the data is loaded, manipulating it (windowing, changing the averaging) is virtually instant, and I use a Core2Duo CPU, not really state of the art.
I suggest you look at your download bandwidth. 
Whatever the bottleneck, reducing your data set before sending it through the wire will help with everything, except fine detail analysis.